# Google Cloud Storage - App Engine Java - Create Upload Url

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I see that there is a way to simply create an upload url like this in python

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_handler', gs_bucket_name='my_bucket')
```

I would like to do exactly the same but in Java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are you looking for this [createUploadUrl](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#createUploadUrl%28java.lang.String%29).

If you go through the [Blobstore Java API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview), at the end there is a fully functional example and they are using the `createUploadUrl()`:

```
String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload", UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("my_bucket"));
```

Comment: Thanks Lipis probably, but could you give me the same sample code that i show in Python but in Java? (i'm a bit curious about the gs_bucket_name stuff)

Comment: Thank you so much i'm gonna try this :)

Comment: mh googleStorageBucketName(); cannot be called because it's not a static method

Comment: @JeromeAnsia I think now it should work now.. I updated my answer:) Sorry, but I never played with GAE on Java

Comment: Still good that you can help me... thanks :) Btw you should always use double quotes for a String in Java -> "my_bucket" ;)

Comment: and... working :) thank you so much :P

Comment: @JeromeAnsia somehow missed that regarding the quotes.. of course :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`googleStorageBucketName`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/UploadOptions#googleStorageBucketName%28java.lang.String%29) property of the UploadOptions, and use the method [`createUploadUrl`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#createUploadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.UploadOptions%29) that receieves options.